# How to control air temperature from Electrolyzer?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

How can I control the emitted air temperature?

1. Cool down the clean water temperature?
2. Put the Electrolyzer in a cool environment?

What else does influence the air temperature?

Comment: Short answer: You can't; the gasses produced are always hot. I'll post a full answer later tonight.

Comment: Fun Fact: Bacteria inside the clean water are going to be in the clean air. But this did nothing else. These Bacteria aren't going to infect the Duplicants or other things like food or items. You would just have many Bacteria inside the Air.

Answer (score 2):

The Electrolyzer always emits gasses at 70°C. The temperature of the input doesn't change this- it'll be the same whether you use boiling geyser water or barely melted ice.

Instead, you need to find ways to cool the output oxygen before sending it into your main base, such as the Thermo Regulator.

Answer (score 0):

Put you air production system (and your power plant) in the cold biom. Also, place "air room" into two sections, that are connected by a 3-high channel. That's where you place some wheezeworts.

Then pipe all that to your base. And there is no need to even bother with isolating the gas pipes, since it will be producing O<sub>2</sub> at something like -30°C.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "two sections, connected with a channel"? How should the air flow from one to the other section? Is it possible for you to upload some screenshot from such an installation?